# No call-to-action in Twitter native apps for Player Card

Tags: android, ios, twitter, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Twitter Player Card docs suggest that in "iPhone and Android native apps, a Player Card will appear in the Tweet detail view **(not in the timeline)**".

There is no explicit mention of how the Player Card will appear in timelines. From experience the link appears as a bare url, without a call-to-action. This is a problem because the user has no idea the link will provide the associated rich content, as can be correctly inferred on other platforms (e.g. static image with 'play' button).

Is there a way to include a CTA for these native apps? Without one, engagement stats are poor.

Example: https://twitter.com/indieHackney/status/1399674190303801348?s=20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have been the author of that original documentation, but I can’t quite remember! The point of the “(not in the timeline)” statement is to say that, indeed, a player card driven from HTML metadata is not shown in the timeline view. I’m not sure how you even get a player to show on click in that Tweet, since the metadata for the page specifies a summary card, which is what is showing up.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Is there a way to conditionally display player cards on desktop and not on mobile? I am sure it is intentional, but the divergent behaviour on desktop/mobile apps makes it quite hard to manage a consistent + engaging user experience.